# Kill idle connections sitting for more than 4 hours

Tags: postgresql, connection, kill

We would like to kill idle connections on Postgres which have been sitting there for more than 4 hours, ideally, we would like to create a cron to do this.

What's the field we should be looking at in the pg_stat_activity? We have these:

```
backend_start
query_start
state_change
```

We assume is backend_start...

We then could do something like this:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
from pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity
where backend_start<CURRENT_TIME-4Hours and state='idle';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the connection rules. If a connection is open only to execute a single transaction (or a group of transactions provided by a batch job), you can virtually kill all idle sessions. When connections are allowed to remain open and wait for new online queries, `state-change` should be considered as this timestamp indicates how long the connection has been idle.

Answer (score 1):

From PostgreSQL v14 on, you can use the `idle_session_timeout` parameter that does exactly that.

Comment: I forgot to say we are using Postgres V9.4

Comment: Then you will have to resort to klin's solution.